# Screen not fully rendering in odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

[image]

After installing OCA **odoo-magento connector** module, screen is not rendering completely, Image is attached here.

Is there any package missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very strange behavior it's resolved by just restarting server.

Answer (score 0):

Please copy the track error. Is posible connector have a confilts with others addons.